# Converting Monthly Data to Daily in R

Tags: r, date

I have a data.frame df that has monthly data:

```
Date           Value 
2008-01-01      3.5          
2008-02-01      9.5          
2008-03-01      0.1
```

I want there to be data on every day in the month (and I will assume Value does not change during each month) since I will be merging this into a different table that has monthly data.

I want the output to look like this:

```
Date           Value 
2008-01-02      3.5
2008-01-03      3.5 
2008-01-04      3.5 
2008-01-05      3.5 
2008-01-06      3.5 
2008-01-07      3.5 
2008-01-08      3.5 
2008-01-09      3.5 
2008-01-10      3.5 
2008-01-11      3.5 
2008-01-12      3.5 
2008-01-13      3.5 
2008-01-14      3.5 
2008-01-15      3.5 
2008-01-16      3.5 
2008-01-17      3.5 
2008-01-18      3.5 
2008-01-19      3.5 
2008-01-20      3.5 
2008-01-21      3.5 
2008-01-22      3.5 
2008-01-23      3.5 
2008-01-24      3.5
2008-01-25      3.5 
2008-01-26      3.5 
2008-01-27      3.5 
2008-01-28      3.5 
2008-01-29      3.5 
2008-01-30      3.5  
2008-01-31      3.5        
2008-02-01      9.5
```

I have tried `to.daily` but my call:

`df <- to.daily(df$Date)`

returns

`Error in to.period(x, "days", name = name, ...) : ‘x’ contains no data`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understood perfectly but i think something like this may work.

First, i define the monthly data table

```
library(data.table)

DT_month=data.table(Date=as.Date(c("2008-01-01","2008-02-01","2008-03-01","2008-05-01","2008-07-01"))
              ,Value=c(3.5,9.5,0.1,5,8))
```

Then, you have to do the following

```
DT_month[,Month:=month(Date)]
DT_month[,Year:=year(Date)]

start_date=min(DT_month$Date)
end_date=max(DT_month$Date)

DT_daily=data.table(Date=seq.Date(start_date,end_date,by="day"))
DT_daily[,Month:=month(Date)]
DT_daily[,Year:=year(Date)]
DT_daily[,Value:=-100]

for( i in unique(DT_daily$Year)){
  for( j in unique(DT_daily$Month)){
    if(length(DT_month[Year==i & Month== j,Value])!=0){
      DT_daily[Year==i & Month== j,Value:=DT_month[Year==i & Month== j,Value]]
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, the code will define the month and year of each monthly value in separate columns.

Then, it will create a vector of daily data using the minimum and maximum dates in your monthly data, and will create two separate columns for year and month for the daily data as well.

Finally, it goes through every combination of year and months of data filling the daily values with the monthly ones. In case there is no data for certain combination of month and year, it will show a -100.

Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

An option using `tidyr::expand` expand a row between 1st day of month to last day of month. The `lubridate::floor_date` can provide 1st day of month and `lubridate::ceiling_date() - days(1)` will provide last day of month.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>%
group_by(Date) %>%
expand(Date = seq(floor_date(Date, unit = "month"),
       ceiling_date(Date, unit="month")-days(1), by="day"), Value) %>%
as.data.frame()

#          Date Value
# 1  2008-01-01   3.5
# 2  2008-01-02   3.5
# 3  2008-01-03   3.5
# 4  2008-01-04   3.5
# 5  2008-01-05   3.5
#.....so on
# 32 2008-02-01   9.5
# 33 2008-02-02   9.5
# 34 2008-02-03   9.5
# 35 2008-02-04   9.5
# 36 2008-02-05   9.5
#.....so on

# 85 2008-03-25   0.1
# 86 2008-03-26   0.1
# 87 2008-03-27   0.1
# 88 2008-03-28   0.1
# 89 2008-03-29   0.1
# 90 2008-03-30   0.1
# 91 2008-03-31   0.1
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Date           Value 
2008-01-01      3.5          
2008-02-01      9.5          
2008-03-01      0.1",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

`to.daily` can only be applied to `xts/zoo`objects and can only convert to a LOWER frequency. i.e. from daily to monthly, but not the other way round.
One easy way to accomplish what you want is converting `df` to an `xts` object:

```
df.xts <- xts(df$Value,order.by = df$Date)
```

And merge, like so:

```
na.locf(merge(df.xts, foo=zoo(NA, order.by=seq(start(df.xts), end(df.xts),
  "day",drop=F)))[, 1])
               df.xts
2018-01-01    3.5
2018-01-02    3.5
2018-01-03    3.5
2018-01-04    3.5
2018-01-05    3.5
2018-01-06    3.5
2018-01-07    3.5
….
2018-01-27    3.5
2018-01-28    3.5
2018-01-29    3.5
2018-01-30    3.5
2018-01-31    3.5
2018-02-01    9.5
2018-02-02    9.5
2018-02-03    9.5
2018-02-04    9.5
2018-02-05    9.5
2018-02-06    9.5
2018-02-07    9.5
2018-02-08    9.5
….
2018-02-27    9.5
2018-02-28    9.5
2018-03-01    0.1
```

If you want to adjust the price continuously over the course of a month use `na.spline` in place of `na.locf`.

Comment: You don't need to use "foo"! moreover, using a very general function like merge needs a namespace

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not an efficient one but with base R we can do

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) 
data.frame(Date = seq(df$Date[i], 
                  (seq(df$Date[i],length=2,by="months") - 1)[2], by = "1 days"), 
                  value = df$Value[i])))
```

We basically generate a `sequence` of dates from `start_date` to the last day of that month which is calculated by

```
seq(df$Date[i],length=2,by="months") - 1)[2]
```

and repeat the same `value` for all the dates and put them in the data frame.

We get a list of dataframe and then we can `rbind` them using `do.call`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
library(lubridate)

d <- read.table(text = "Date           Value 
                2008-01-01      3.5          
                2008-02-01      9.5          
                2008-03-01      0.1",
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

Dates <- seq(from = min(as.Date(d$Date)),
             to = ceiling_date(max(as.Date(d$Date)), "month") - days(1),
             by = "1 days")

data.frame(Date = Dates,
           Value = setNames(d$Value, d$Date)[format(Dates, format = "%Y-%m-01")])
```