# Is there an R function to go from monthly to daily data by repeating the monthly value every day?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a monthly interest rate. I would like to represent this information as a "daily" interest rate and have the monthly rate repeat every day until the new month when it is updated. The purpose is for daily reporting, and the interest rate is one of the metrics.

Assuming my date column is year-day-month...

```
df.int = data.frame(c('2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04'),
                    c(0.02321,0.02198,0.01985,0.02011))

colnames(df.int) = c('Date','Interest Rate')
```

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

We could create a daily date range of the desired length and then join on that based on the month of those dates:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

#convert Date to Date and create month variable
df.int <- df.int %>% 
  mutate(Date = ydm(Date),
         month = month(Date))

#create daily sequence with min-max date range based on min/max date of df.int$Date
daily_df <- tibble(date = seq(min(df.int$Date), max(df.int$Date), "days")) %>% 
  mutate(month = month(date))

#join based on month
daily_df %>% 
  left_join(df.int, "month") %>% 
  select(-date)

# A tibble: 92 x 3
   month Date       `Interest Rate`
   <dbl> <date>               <dbl>
 1     1 2020-01-01          0.0232
 2     1 2020-01-01          0.0232
 3     1 2020-01-01          0.0232
 4     1 2020-01-01          0.0232
 5     1 2020-01-01          0.0232
 6     1 2020-01-01          0.0232
 7     1 2020-01-01          0.0232
 8     1 2020-01-01          0.0232
 9     1 2020-01-01          0.0232
10     1 2020-01-01          0.0232
# ... with 82 more rows
```

**Data**

```
df.int = data.frame(c('2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04'),
                    c(0.02321,0.02198,0.01985,0.02011))

colnames(df.int) = c('Date','Interest Rate')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread after some more researching that answered my problem!

[Converting Monthly Data to Daily in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50167509/converting-monthly-data-to-daily-in-r)