# Convert year-wise data to day-wise?

Tags: r, date

I am working towards the goal of setting a variable that indicates whether two people worked together for a full year or partial year.  By that I mean did their work days overlap for the full year (Jan 1 to Dec 31) or part of the year across multiple years. In my data, (small sample included below), I have the start and end dates for both workers and bosses.

```
df = data.table(worker_term_start=as.Date(c("2008-04-01")),
                worker_term_end=as.Date(c("2009-12-31")),
                worker_name = c("Tim"),
                boss_term_start=as.Date(c("2008-01-01")),
                boss_term_end=as.Date(c("2009-12-31")),
                boss_name = c("Emily"))
```

Here is what the output might look like, where data is expanded day-wise and all other values are repeated. Apologies if the code is unclear, I attached an image of the output from this code.

```
df_daily = data.table(worker_term_start=as.Date(c("2008-04-01")), #with term start repeated for each row
                      worker_term_end=as.Date(c("2009-12-31")), #with term end repeated for each row
                      worker_term_date=as.Date(c("2008-04-01",
                                                    "2008-04-02",
                                                    "2008-04-03",
                                                    "2008-04-04",
                                                    "2008-04-05",
                                                    "2008-04-06",
                                                    "2008-04-07",
                                                    "2008-04-08",
                                                    "2008-04-09",
                                                    "2008-04-10",
                                                    "2008-04-11",
                                                    "2008-04-12",
                                                    "2008-04-13",
                                                  "2008-04-14",
                                                  "2008-04-15",
                                                  "2008-04-16",
                                                  "2008-04-17",
                                                  "2008-04-18",
                                                  "2008-04-19",
                                                  "2008-04-20",
                                                  "2008-04-21",
                                                  "2008-04-22",
                                                  "2008-04-23",
                                                  "2008-04-24",
                                                  "2008-04-25",
                                                  "2008-04-26",
                                                  "2008-04-27",
                                                  "2008-04-28",
                                                  "2008-04-29",
                                                  "2008-04-30")),
                      worker_name = c("Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim",
                                      "Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim",
                                      "Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim",
                                      "Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim","Tim"),
                      boss_term_start = as.Date(c("2008-01-01")), #repeated for each row day-wise
                      boss_term_end = as.Date(c("2009-12-31")),
                      boss_term_date = as.Date(c("2008-01-01", "2008-01-02")),
                      boss_name = c("Emily", "Emily"))
```

([Image attached for what the end result might look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW1Lt.png))
As an initial step, I managed to expand day-wise using a loop, but I’m not retaining all of the values from the original dataset. In my sample, I only included two columns for values (worker_name and boss_name) but my real data has 20 values to preserve. I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50167509/converting-monthly-data-to-daily-in-r) to create my loop, and the error message I got when working with my real data was: Supplied 11 items to be assigned to 31 items of column 'variable_name'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

```
df[,Month:=month(worker_term_start)]
df[,Year:=year(worker_term_end)]
start_date=min(df$worker_term_start)
end_date=max(df$worker_term_end)
df_daily=data.table(Date=seq.Date(start_date, end_date, by="day"))
df_daily[,Month:=month(Date)]
df_daily[,Year:=year(Date)]
df_daily[,worker_name:="Tim"]

for( i in unique(df_daily$Year)){
  for( j in unique(df_daily$Month)){
    if(length(df[Year ==i & Month ==j, worker_name])!=0){
      df_daily[Year==i & Month==j, worker_name:=alignment[Year==i & Month== j, worker_name]]
    }
  }
}
```

In this loop, I've only included the value for worker_name, but ideally I would have the data filled day-wise for both worker and boss, and keep both values for the names. Is there a way using a loop to resolve this error and fill the values for multiple variables?

Answer (score 0):

The number of days for worker and boss are not the same which will make the long dataframe uneven. We can calculate the max value between worker term and boss term and append the shorter duration with `NA`s.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(max_Diff = as.integer(pmax(worker_term_end - worker_term_start, 
                                     boss_term_end  -boss_term_start)),
         worker_term_date = pmap(list(worker_term_start, worker_term_end, max_Diff), 
                                ~seq(..1, ..2, by = '1 day')[1:..3]),
         boss_term_date = pmap(list(boss_term_start, boss_term_end, max_Diff),
                                ~seq(..1, ..2, by = '1 day')[1:..3])) %>%
  unnest(c(worker_term_date, boss_term_date)) %>%
  tail


#  worker_term_start worker_term_end worker_name boss_term_start boss_term_end boss_name max_Diff worker_term_date boss_term_date
#  <date>            <date>          <chr>       <date>          <date>        <chr>        <int> <date>           <date>        
#1 2008-04-01        2009-12-31      Tim         2008-01-01      2009-12-31    Emily          730 NA               2009-12-25    
#2 2008-04-01        2009-12-31      Tim         2008-01-01      2009-12-31    Emily          730 NA               2009-12-26    
#3 2008-04-01        2009-12-31      Tim         2008-01-01      2009-12-31    Emily          730 NA               2009-12-27    
#4 2008-04-01        2009-12-31      Tim         2008-01-01      2009-12-31    Emily          730 NA               2009-12-28    
#5 2008-04-01        2009-12-31      Tim         2008-01-01      2009-12-31    Emily          730 NA               2009-12-29    
#6 2008-04-01        2009-12-31      Tim         2008-01-01      2009-12-31    Emily          730 NA               2009-12-30
```

Here I am showing last 6 rows where we can see that `worker_term_date` has `NA`'s whereas `boss_term_date` has date till end that is because worker starts on `2008-04-01` whereas boss starts on `2008-01-01`.